# Return mean value without tuple?

Tags: python

Expected output: report_exam_avg(100, 95, 80) == 'Your average score: 91.7'

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    assert is_number(a) and is_number(b) and is_number(c)

    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)
    mean = (a + b + c) / 3.0    
    mean = round(mean,1)    
    x = 'Your average score: ', mean
    return x
```

Actual output: ('Your average score: ', 91.7)

Note: cant unpack the tuple such as below because I need the sentence returned not printed

```
avg, score = report_exam_avg(100, 95, 80)
print(avg, score)
```

Comment: `x = 'Your average score: ' + str(mean)`

Comment: x = 'Your average score: %s ', mean; print(avg % score)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning x as a tuple in this case. So this is why when you simply print x you get a tuple as output. You should either use the print statement in Function or modify function as follows:

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
assert is_number(a) and is_number(b) and is_number(c)

a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
mean = (a + b + c) / 3.0    
mean = round(mean,1)    
x =  mean
return x
```

So your call to function would be:

```
print ("Your Avg. Score:", report_exam_avg(100, 95, 80))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the use of the comma to plus. This would change where you set the variable x:

```
x = 'Your average score: ' + str(mean)
```

This will properly handle string concatenation, whereas the comma will generate a tuple.

Additionally, if you are using python 3.6, you could make use of fstrings, a very handy string interpolation tool. This would change the line to look like this:

```
x = f'Your average score: {mean}'
```

You can then return x in string form.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports return multiple values in a function, just delimit them with `,`. In your case, Python thinks you'are doing this, thus returns a tuple.

To return a string, simply concat string with `+`:

```
x = 'Your average score: ' + str(mean)
return x
```

Or, use string format

```
x = 'Your average score: {}'.format(mean)
return x
```